# Eval times for this function alternate b/w 85 nanosec and 10 sec (!?)

Tags: performance, clojure, benchmarking, read-eval-print-loop

### Objective

I'm trying to figure out why a function I've created, `items-staged-f`, has both such strangely  long and short evaluation times.

### Strange, you say?

I say "strange" because:

- `(time (items-staged-f))` yields `1.313 msecs`
- `(time (items-staged-f))` a second time yields `0.035 msecs` (which is unsurprising, because the result is a lazy sequence and it must have been memoized)
- The [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) benchmarking system reports it taking `85.149767 ns` (which is unsurprising)

And yet...

- The time it takes to actually evaluate `(items-staged-f)` in the REPL is around ***10 seconds***. This is even before it prints anything. I was originally thinking that it takes that long likely because it's preparing to print to the REPL, because it's a long and complex data structure (nested maps and vectors in a lazy sequence), but it's just strange that the result wouldn't even start printing out until 10 seconds later when it (supposedly) takes 85 nanoseconds. Could it be that it's pre-calculating how to print the data structure?
- `(time (last (items-staged-f)))` yields **`10498.16 msecs`** (although this varies up to around 20 seconds), possibly for the same reason above.

### And now for the code...

The goal of the function `items-staged-f` is to visualize what needs to be done in order to make some necessary changes to inventory items in an accounting database.

Unfamiliar functions referenced within `items-staged-f` may be found below.

```
(defn items-staged-f []
  (let [items-0 (lazy-seq (items-staged :items))
        both-types? #(in? % (group+line-items))
        items-from-group #(get items-0 %)
        replace-subgroups
          (fn [[g-item l-items :as group]]
            (let [items-in-both
                    (->> l-items
                         (map :item)
                         (filter both-types?))]
              (->> (concat
                        (remove #(in? (:item %)  items-in-both) l-items)
                        (mapcat items-from-group items-in-both))
                   (into [])
                   (assoc group 1))))
        replaced (map replace-subgroups items-0)]
   replaced))
```

**`items-staged`** is a function which outputs the original data which `items-staged-f` manipulates. `(items-staged :items)` outputs a map with string-keys (group items) whose values are vectors of maps (lists of sub-items):

```
{"786M" ; this is a group item
 ; below are the sub-items of the above group item
 [{:description "Signature Collection Item", :item "4X1"}
  {:description "Cookies, Inc. Paper Wrapped", :item "65G7"}
  {:description "MyChocolate 5 oz.", :item "21F"}]}
```

*Note that the output of `items-staged-f` is almost identical in structure to that of `items-staged`, except it is a lazy sequence of vectors instead of a hash-map with hash-map-entries, as would be expected by calling the `map` function on a hash-map.*

**`in?`** is a predicate which checks if an object is in a given collection. For example, `(in? 1 [1 2 3])` evaluates to `true`.

**`group+line-items`** is a function which outputs a lazy sequence of certain duplicate items I wish to eliminate. For example, `(group+line-items)` evaluates to: `("428X" "41SF" "6998" "75D22")`

### Notes

VisualVM 1.3.8 is saying that clojure.lang.Reflector.getMethods() clocks in at 28700 ms (51.3%), clojure.lang.LineNumberingPushbackReader.read() (is this because of the output in the REPL?) at 9000 ms (16.2%), and clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom() at 7800 ms (13.9%).

However, when I evaluate each element of the lazy sequence `(nth items-staged-f n)` individually in the REPL, only clojure.lang.LineNumberingPushbackReader.read() ever goes up. The invocations go up in increments of 32, which is the lazy-seq chunking size. Time elapsed for other methods/functions is negligible.

One other consideration is that `items-staged` is a function which ultimately draws its data from an Excel file (read via [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org)). However, the raw data from the Excel file is stored as a var, so that shouldn't be an issue because it would only calculate once before being memoized (I think).

---

**Thanks for your help!**

### *Addendum*

Once I used `doall` to force realization on the lazy sequence (which I thought was being realized), Criterium now says the function takes `11.370356 sec` to evaluate, which unfortunately makes sense. I'll repost once I refactor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lazy-sequences by definition calculate their elements only when required. Printing to the REPL or requesting the `last` element both force realization. Timing the function call that produces the lazy sequence does not.

```
(defn slow-and-lazy [] (map #(do (Thread/sleep 1000) (inc %)) (range 10)))

user=> (time (slow-and-lazy))
"Elapsed time: 0.837002 msecs"
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) ; printed 10 seconds later

user=> (time (doall (slow-and-lazy)))
"Elapsed time: 10000.205709 msecs"
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

In the case of `(time (slow-and-lazy))`, `slow-and-lazy` quickly returns an unrealized lazy-sequence and `time` finishes, printing the elapsed time and passing along the unrealized result in this case to the REPL. Then, the REPL attempts to print the sequence. In order to do so, it must realize the sequence.

---

That having been said, 10 seconds is an eternity for a computer, so this does warrant examination/profiling. I would suggest refactoring your code into smaller self-contained functions. In particular, the data should be passed in as arguments. Once you nail down the bottleneck (time with `doall` to force realization!), then consider posting a new question. Without being able to tell exactly what's going on with this code or whether IO in `items-staged` is the true bottleneck, there still seems to be room for improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. I wasn't aware of the fact that `(time (slow-and-lazy))` prints the timing right away but realizes the whole sequence to print it. I'll refactor the code and post an update.

Comment: @alexandergunnarson You can accept this answer (checkmark to the left of answer) if it addressed the immediate question. Then, post any subproblems you find as new, separate question(s).